# Assigning to list in while loop for python 3

Tags: python, list, variables, while-loop, increment

I've got the following bit of python code:

```
# we are going to define a list:

charList = []

#which we can use to add character's data to

i = 0

print("Please input data for your first character below: ")

while i <= 5:
    charList[i] = input("What is their name? ")
    i += 1 # increments i by 1
    charList[i] = input("\nAnd what is their strength value? ")
    i += 1
    charList[i] = input("\nAnd what is their skill value? ")
    i += 1
    print("\nThank You :)\n")
    print("Now for your second character:")

print(charList[0],charList[3])
```

This is for version 3.4.0.

It comes up with the following error:

```
>>> 
Please input data for your first character below: 
What is their name? Chewbacca
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/Documents/ARCHIVES/NEW!/Computing/task3version1.0.py", line 20, in <module>
    charList[i] = input("What is their name? ")
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
>>>
```

I am guessing it is to do with an issue of i's value being changed while in the while loop. Any ideas as to what is wrong? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Accessing indices of a list, like in `charList[i]`, is there to access/manipulate existing elements of the list. Since `charList` starts out empty there are no elements that could be accessed. Trying to do so will give you an out of range error, as you have seen.

Instead you seem to want to *append* to the list, like this:

```
charList.append(input("What is their name? "))
```

Comment: i've also tried originally setting the list to something 9eg. j = [0,0,0,0,0] before adding new variables in and that works as well

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do it in a cycle? You're trying to rewriting same list 5 times.

```
questions = ("What is their name? ", "\nAnd what is their strength value? ", "\nAnd what is their skill value? ")
print("Please input data for your first character below: ")
charlist = [input(i) for i in questions]
print("\nThank You :)\n")
print(charList[0],charList[3])
```

If you want several characters:

```
charlist = []
questions = ("What is their name? ", "\nAnd what is their strength value? ", "\nAnd what is their skill value? ")
print("Please input data for your first character below: ")
for i in range(5):
    character = [input(i) for i in questions]
    charlist.append(character)
    print("\nThank You :)\n")
print(charList[0][0],charList[3][0])
```

Comment: I was attempting to add names/characteristics of characters to a list, so I could then use them as variables later (eg. print(charList[0], "has x skill remaining")

Comment: Maybe you wanted to add them in a list of lists? Or, idk, dictionary of name:list. charList[0] should be a character or his name? If it is a name, how you tell between different characters?